# data.table with unique names from nested list with different classes and missing names

Tags: r, data.table

I have a nested list of this structure:

```
test_list <- list(
  "some string",
  list(type = "entry_type", text = "some content"),
  list("more strings"),
  list(type = "another_type", text = "more text yet"),
  ""
)
```

So it is a list containing lists and plain entries, while the only names are those of the items of the nested lists - which are duplicated.

My goal is to transfer this into a data.table with the original names (provided they exist) but made unique.

Currently I use this pipeline:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(flatten(test_list))

unique_names <- paste0("V", seq_len(length(names(dt))))
propper_names <- names(dt)

new_names <- propper_names

blank_names <- which(new_names == "")
new_names[blank_names] <- unique_names[blank_names]

duplicates_names <- which(duplicated(new_names))
new_names[duplicates_names] <- paste(
  propper_names[duplicates_names],
  unique_names[duplicates_names],
  sep = "_"
  )

setnames(
  dt,
  new_names
)
```

Is there a nicer/faster/better/more robust way to accomplish this goal?

Comment: Where does `flatten()` come from?

Answer (score 0):

You could use unlist `rapply()` to retain the deeper-nested names:

```r
setDT(as.list(rapply(test_list, identity)))[]
setnames(DT, make.names(names(DT), unique = TRUE))
DT
#             V1       type         text           V2       type.1        text.1 V3
# 1: some string entry_type some content more strings another_type more text yet
```